# Получить ephemeral сообщения из канала дискорда

Tags: discord, discord-api

В дискорде есть сообщения, которые видны только пользователю, для которого они пришли от бота. Могу ли я с помощью API или каким-то еще методом получить эти сообщения из канала(с помощью своих же, конечно же, данных авториации)? Я пытался сделать это с помощью [https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/{self.channelid}/messages?limit={100}](https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/%7Bself.channelid%7D/messages?limit=%7B100%7D) , но здесь я получаю только обычные сообщения. Эфемерные таким образом у меня получить не получилось. Сломал уже всю голову, подскажите, если кто-нибудь знает.
Бот не мой, но канал и аккаунт, с которого я использую команды этого бота, и куда приходят эти сообщения - мои, и глазами я их в чате вижу.